# Is it typical that smoke detectors in adjacent apartments be linked?

Tags: code-compliance, smoke-detectors

I rent the downstairs apt of what used to be a garage. There is one other unit located on the second floor. My smoke alarm was going off frequently without my knowing why. Landlord finally told me this last (9th) time, that the upstairs and downstairs smoke alarms are hard wired together so I know if my neighbor has set their place on fire, and vice versa. Needed to be that way to be up to code.

Is this a normal occurrence? Thanks.

Comment: I think most places now require multi-family units to have interconnected fire alarms, some even require single-family units to have interconnected alarms.  I'll try and locate a code reference.

Comment: Having linked alarms sounds like a great idea since it sounds like the apartment was an owner conversion so  you probably don't have rated fire walls between dwellings as you might in a purpose built multi-dwelling building. But since you're getting so many false alarms, it's probably worth talking with the landlord (and/or tenant upstairs) to find out why - maybe the alarm is too close to a kitchen or bathroom, or maybe a different alarm would be less prone to false alarms (or easier to hush), or maybe they just need to open a window when making toast.

Comment: @Tester101 if an area has adopted the recent International Residential Code it calls for interconnects only on new construction or when remodeling removes walls/ceilings that permit rewiring for that purpose.

Comment: @JeffMeden That's true for most code changes. However, with multi-family units, sometimes other governing bodies are involved.  Upgrades may be required at annual inspections, or due to other licensing type reasons.  It really depends on the local government.

Comment: @Tester101 true, but two-family dwellings are almost always grouped with single family ones, as governed by places that adopt the IRC.  The IBC kicks in once you get into true multifamily (R-1 10 or more occupants).

Comment: Thanks Johnny. That makes the most sense seeing as it was the owners first construction project. When I asked my neighbors what was happening one replied "it only happens when we have the oven set at over 450°." Why they have the need to do so was not my question to ask. Each apartment is only 600 sq ft and is all tile.

Comment: @Dawn -- it sounds like they need to clean their oven -- (some recipes do call for an oven that hot)

Comment: Sounds best to have it wired this way. I'd definitely want to know if my neighbor caught the place on fire. That's why you don't have renters insurance just for yourself, you have it include every unit in the building (as far as fire could spread quickly) because the building is only as safe as the dumbest person. -- On the oven and such, it might be a heat detector. Same concept, but it goes off when it gets so hot because heat rises.

Comment: I wish kitchen smoke alarms would provide a feature to delay activation of other alarms for 5-10 seconds or so, along with a contact-closure input for a "hush" function that could be connected to a wall-mounted button.  If someone in the immediate vicinity of an alarm knows why it's going off, and knows that it poses is no danger to other building occupants, having all of the alarms in a building go off is just an annoying nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your building/fire code jurisdiction, some do and some do not.  More importantly, if the garage is a separately occupied dwelling it should be isolated from the other apartment via fire-resistant materials.  This presumption (which is almost always a part of the local building code) is what alleviates the need for an interconnected alarm in the practical sense.  If it's not, I would sleep well knowing that a fire in the other unit would trigger the alarm and wake me up.